# How to disable screen unlock on mouse move

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, energy-saving

I have an openSUSE Leap 15.2 KDE desktop which runs 24/7 but the screen turns on every time my cat jumps on the table :( (:

That's why I would like to turn on the screen only on keyboard interaction but not on mouse move.

Is there a way to disable screen unlock on mouse move?

Thanks
Marc

Comment: You could flip the mouse over. That's what I used to do before macOS introduced the spacebar only wake method & stopped the mouse being an influence.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the creative workaround but it's not what I was looking for

Comment: I guessed that;)) It used to be the only way on Mac, there was no way to disable it in the system. I'm really glad they eventually changed it.